# is there a way to install the nodebox English linguistics library through pip install?

Tags: nlp, pip, nodebox

The [NodeBox English linguistic library](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics) for Python has some nice features, like conjugation, that could be very useful for a project.

I tried installing through pip in a particular virtualenv, but `pip search nodebox` only brings up:

```
NodeBox                   - Simple application for creating 2-dimensional
                            graphics and animation using Python code
nodebox-color             - Color classes for python
NodeBox-for-OpenGL        - 2D animation with Python code
nodebox-opengl            - NodeBox for OpenGL is a free, cross-platform
                            library for generating 2D animations with Python
                            programming code.
```

Is it pip-installable (in a virtualenv) by another name maybe? Or is the only way to install to

> Put the en library folder in the same folder as your script so NodeBox
>   can find the library. You can also put it in `~/Library/Application
>   Support/NodeBox/`. It takes some time to load all the data the first
>   time.

as stated on their website?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Nodebox library has been succeeded by [pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pattern), which is on the PyPI. The NLP functionality is contained in the `pattern.en` module. It can be installed with:

```
pip install pattern
```

Comment: thanks!! I saw that at least one of the authors of pattern was mentioned somewhere in the nodebox website but I thought nodebox was a bit of a tangential project. is this info somewhere on any of their websites?

Comment: Is the project abandoned? 1 year without updates https://github.com/clips/pattern

Comment: @giorgio79 Might be – doesn't install in Python3.

Comment: aigh... pattern, which is still stuck on python 2

Comment: pattern now works with Python 3, although it's still poorly maintained and has a lot of bugs.